# How can I pass model information in a ng-repeat to a parent directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slick.js

It's been a while since I did anything in AngularJS so this is probably fairly simple.

I have a carousel of items (using [angular-slick-carousel](https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel/)) which are produced using an `ng-repeat`, eg:

```
<slick settings="slickConfigGlobal">
        <span ng-repeat="q in questions">
            {{ q.title }}
        </span>
</slick>
```

In `slickConfigGlobal` I have a callback bound to the `afterChange` event that Slick (the carousel) exposes, eg. when the user chooses a new question:

```
$scope.slickConfigGlobal.event = {
    afterChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        var slide = slick.$slides[currentSlide];
    }
};
```

My problem: I want to access `q` inside this callback, eg. the question the user has selected. I can grab the DOM element they've chosen, but what I need is the actual model value the selected slide represents. How can I pass this around?